# Is Internet required to activate Kinect?

Tags: kinect

Do you have to have Internet on your Xbox 360 to activate the Kinect?

Comment: Well it directly had to get an update, so I figure you need internet regardless of activation

Comment: I was able to play on my parent's unconnected Xbox on Christmas morning. Not sure if the update came from the Kinect Adventures game or from the device itself, but it definitely installed an update and worked just fine.

Answer (score 9):

No, Kinect comes with an update on it for drivers and stuff it needs to work.

Once you connect to the internet it does take a new update, but you don't need the internet (or that update) to use Kinect right out of the box.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that some time in the future Microsoft will not allow Kinect users with a depreciated software through XBox Live because they are becoming a security threat.

Comment: @Bora what do you mean? IIRC if you don't have the latest system update you can't get online, regardless of whether you have Kinect or not.

Comment: I wasn't talking about activating Kinect, but also playing with it online. That's why only as a comment.

Answer (score 3):

The Kinect games all have the required updates on the discs.  It will prompt you to download the update (from the disc) when you try to play the game.  I believe future titles will require you to download updates from their discs as well.

There are plenty of people who play kinect without an internet connection, so I wouldn't worry about it.  Assuming you have the newest version of Xbox (unofficially called the "slim"), you can turn on wifi and try to connect to a neighbors connection just for updates, but of course this is frowned upon. :)